# Spring Boot Redis configuration not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

I am developing a Spring Boot [web] REST-style application with a `ServletInitializer` (since it needs to be deployed to an existing Tomcat server). It has a `@RestController` with a method that, when invoked, needs to write to a Redis `pub-sub channel`. I have the Redis server running on localhost (default port, no password). The relevant part of the POM file has the required starter dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

When I deploy the WAR and hit the endpoint `http://localhost:8080/springBootApp/health`, I get this response:

```
{
  "status": "DOWN",
  "diskSpace": {
    "status": "UP",
    "total": 999324516352,
    "free": 691261681664,
    "threshold": 10485760
  },
  "redis": {
    "status": "DOWN",
    "error": "org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out; nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out"
  }
}
```

I added the following to my Spring Boot application class:

```
@Bean
JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
    return new JedisConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

I also tried adding the following to my `@RestController` before executing some test Redis code, but I get the same error as above in the stack trace:

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;
```

**Edit** (2017-05-09)
My understanding is that Spring Boot Redis starter assumes the default values of `spring.redis.host=localhost` and `spring.redis.port=6379`, I still added the two to `application.properties`, but that did not fill the gap.

**Update** (2017-05-10)
I added an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a proxy related problem, where even access to localhost was somehow being curtailed. Once I disabled the proxy settings, Redis health was `UP`! So the problem is solved. I did not have to add any property to `application.properties` and neither did I have to explicitly configure anything in the Spring Boot application class, because Spring Boot and the Redis Starter auto-configures based on Redis defaults (as applicable in my development environment). I just added the following to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

and the following to the `@RestController` annotated class, and Spring Boot auto-wired as needed (awesome!).

```
@Autowired
private RedisTemplate<String, String> redisTemplate;
```

To publish a simple message to a channel, this single line of code was sufficient for validating the setup:

```
this.redisTemplate.convertAndSend(channelName, "hello world");
```

I appreciate all the comments, which were helpful in backing up my checks.

Answer (score 5):

[Spring data redis properties are updated](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#REDIS), e.g. `spring.redis.host` is now `spring.data.redis.host`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. looks like config got changed for spring boot 3

Answer (score 2):

I done a simple example with redis and spring boot

First I installed redis on docker:

**$ docker run --name some-redis -d redis redis-server --appendonly yes**

Then I Used this code for receiver :

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class Receiver {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);

    private CountDownLatch latch;

    @Autowired
    public Receiver(CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    public void receiveMessage(String message) {
        LOGGER.info("Received <" + message + ">");
        latch.countDown();
    }

}
```

And this is my spring boot app and my listener:

```
@SpringBootApplication
// after add security library then it is need to use security configuration.
@ComponentScan("omid.spring.example.springexample.security")
public class RunSpring {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunSpring.class);


    public  static   void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext contex =  SpringApplication.run(RunSpring.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @RestController
    public class SimpleController{

        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public String getHelloWorld(){

            StringRedisTemplate template = context.getBean(StringRedisTemplate.class);
            CountDownLatch latch = context.getBean(CountDownLatch.class);

            LOGGER.info("Sending message...");

            Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0 ;  i < 100 ; i++) {
                        template.convertAndSend("chat", i + " => Hello from Redis!");
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(100);
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                }
            });
            t.start();

            try {
                latch.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return "hello world 1";
        }
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    @Bean
    RedisMessageListenerContainer container(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                            MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {

        RedisMessageListenerContainer container = new RedisMessageListenerContainer();
        container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        container.addMessageListener(listenerAdapter, new PatternTopic("chat"));

        return container;
    }

    @Bean
    MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter(Receiver receiver) {
        return new MessageListenerAdapter(receiver, "receiveMessage");
    }

    @Bean
    Receiver receiver(CountDownLatch latch) {
        return new Receiver(latch);
    }

    @Bean
    CountDownLatch latch() {
        return new CountDownLatch(1);
    }

    @Bean
    StringRedisTemplate template(RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new StringRedisTemplate(connectionFactory);
    }
}
```

The important point is the redis IP. if you installed it on docker like me then
you should set ip address in application.properties like this:
**spring.redis.host=172.17.0.4**

I put all my spring examples on github [here](https://github.com/omidmohebbise/springexample)

In addition I used redis stat to monitor redis. it is simple monitoring. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your redis server information using the application.properties:

```
# REDIS (RedisProperties)
spring.redis.cluster.nodes= # Comma-separated list of "host:port"
spring.redis.database=0 # Database index
spring.redis.url= # Connection URL, 
spring.redis.host=localhost # Redis server host.
spring.redis.password= # Login password of the redis server.
spring.redis.ssl=false # Enable SSL support.
spring.redis.port=6379 # Redis server port.
```

Spring data docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#REDIS

Comment: Since I am using Redis locally (fresh install, no configuration changes), I thought Spring Boot Redis starter assumes those defaults. I am not using a cluster. The only Redis properties that are applicable would be `spring.redis.host` (localhost) and `spring.redis.port` (6379).

Comment: Is your redis service running. Were you able to connect the service through redis-cli? Your code looks good...

Comment: Hi @PraneethRamesh my redis server is running. Verifications I ran included `telnet localhost 6379` *(was able to telnet into that port)* and writing a testing GET based method in the controller to open a socket using `Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 6379); return s.isConnected();` *(which yielded true)*. So I know Redis is running and accessible to the JVM. And yes, I am able to connect to service with redis-cli.